# Two kind of lags/delays between buffers

Tags: algorithm, buffer, lag, rolling-computation

Suppose we are getting data at the same frequency from two sources, S1 and S2, and we want to multiply them. However, S1 is noisy and we decide we want to take a rolling average three values of A before multiplying it with S2. Then we arrive at the following situation:

- We have two buffers, B1 and B2, in which are stored the inputs of S1 and S2.
- Some program P1 computes the rolling average from buffer B1, whose result is stored in buffer B3.
- Finally program P2 multiplies the results in buffers B2 and B3 and outputs a result.

There are two different things that could be called "lag". Suppose the data arrived at time t, t+1s and t+2s.

- Then we want the P1 output to be stored at time t+1s (in order for P2 to multiply it by the appropriate value from B2). So there is a lag of 1s between B1/B2 and B3 (i.e: the last value in B3 is always late by 1 compared to the last values stored in B1/B2).
- But the first output of P1 is only produced at time t+2s. This is important because it informs us on when we can launch P2 for the first time. So in this sense there has to be a 2s delay on B3 compared and B1/B2.

My question is: do these different kind of lags have names? and perhaps what is the right way to deal with them?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first type of lag would be referred to as *Lead Time*-  the amount of time between when input is first given, and when any result is returned. The best may to mitigate this type of lag is seemingly to avoid starting / stopping where possible, to avoid the overhead.

The second type of lag I would just call general *Latency*- the delay between a cause (input) and its associated effect. What can be done to address latency depends a lot on context. Sometimes a process can be parallelized to minimize the time elapsed between start / stop. Sometimes rearranging the task ordering can allow for more efficient pipelining, reducing latency. Sometimes, there's nothing that can be done at all.